# How apply a storyboard to a Label programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I've a little problem, I'd search google and my Wpf's books but I don't found any answer :(

I have created a little storyboard :

```
<Storyboard x:Key="whiteAnim" Duration="1">
        <ColorAnimation By="Black" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" x:Name="step1"/>
        <ColorAnimation By="White" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" x:Name="step2"/>
</Storyboard>
```

This animation will change background color from black to white, and from white to black.
I want to "apply" this storyboard to a Label :

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Content = "My label";
```

I'm looking for a method like "label.StartStoryboard(--myStoryboard--), do you have any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with

```
public void StartStoryboard() {
  whiteAnim.Target = label;
  whiteAnim.Begin();
}
```

or

```
public void StartStoryboard() {
  Storyboard.SetTarget(whiteAnim, label);
  whiteAnim.Begin();
}
```